# Do add-in commands in Outlook supersede custom panes?

Tags: outlook, office-addins, office-js, office365-apps

If I add the VersionOverrides element to define a custom Ribbon button to launch a task pane for my add-in, the tab for my custom pane is no longer visible in Outlook 2016, but it is in Outlook Online/OWA.  It is defined without any activation rules so it should appear for every read message.  So is it a bug or by design that the tab is hidden if I've defined a custom Ribbon button to launch it?  If I remove the VersionOverrides element the tab appears again.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Nov 2016. For Outlook add-ins custom panes are considered absolete
https://dev.office.com/blogs/make-your-add-ins-available-in-the-office-ribbon

***Old answer:***

I have discussed similar topic with a Senior Product Manager of Office extensibility. I hope he would not mind if I quote him. Outlook web add-ins Custom panes should be considered:

> just legacy support for clients which don't today support Office commands. Commands provide a much more intuitive, natural and engaging way to use add-ins, which is why we’re pushing for them very hard.

Having said that, OWA does not support commands yet. Owa looks in your manifest for the old `FormSettings` element and display your custom pane same as before when add-ins commands did not exist. Same thing for Office 2016 when there is no `VersionOverrides` element in your manifest for retro-compatibility purposes.

Now it is difficult for us, add-ins developers, to propose now an add-in with completely different UX between OWA and Desktop. Then, if you want to have the Custom Pane working with Add-ins commands in Outlook Desktop 2016 (only host that supports commands at the time of the writing) you have to specified it with an `ExtensionPoint` with type `xsi:type="CustomPane"` in your `VersionOverrides` see this example

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomPane">
              <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
              <SourceLocation resid="customPaneUrl"/>
              <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message"/>
              </Rule>
            </ExtensionPoint>

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                    <Tooltip resid="paneReadButtonTooltip" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="test-icon-80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="taskPaneUrl" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>

      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit.  What they also need to consider is that the UX for a mostly horizontal custom pane is challenging to design so it works equally well in a narrower, vertically oriented task pane. It would be nice if they can support a horizontal task pane in this regard.

Comment: I totally agree. Does my answer helped you?

Comment: I understand the mechanics - we're both experts in this area - but I'm specifically looking for confirmation from MS or documentation that states that declaration of add-in commands overrides the add-in's declaration for display as a custom pane add-in. I'll follow up with the team in Yammer

Comment: Eric, i'm not sure i understand - you're saying you defined a custom pane extension point AND add-in commands in version overrides, but only commands appear? i can't repro that - can you paste your manifest?